# jenkins not responding to github webhook`

Tags: github, jenkins, githooks

I got Jenkins talking to Github, and manually I can initiate a build and it succeeds! This is a private Github repo.

I can't get the webhook to work, so that when I check-in in my repo, Jenkins would pull and auto build?

I put a service hook under Jenkins (GitHub plugin). Testing the hook shows "Payload deployed"

This is what my hook looks like
http://myjenkinsurl.com:8080/github-webhook/

In the Jenkins config, I selected "Manually manage hook URLs"

Comment: Before doing anything else, you should enable security on Jenkins. I certainly hope that server is not on your main network because anyone with your Jenkins URL (And you have now broadcast it to the public) can currently execute any script on that server. I am editing the question to remove the actual url, but it is still in the edit history. You should never include actual url's in a question.

Comment: To answer your actual question, you will need to set up a Webhook in GitHub for a specific job and a specific repository. Note that Jenkins will not pull anything in this scenario, it will wait for GitHub to notify that a checkin has been made.

Comment: @meta did you ever find the solution to your issue?